# Django CMS:: Deserialization Error :: page has no field named 'path'

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have a Django application which is using Django CMS. I had built custom plugins, pages, users etc. in the application using CMS. I want to export the CMS data from my application to another instance of the same application which doesn't have any cms related data.

I am using the following command:

```
python manage.py dumpdata cms djangocms_column djangocms_file djangocms_googlemap djangocms_link djangocms_picture djangocms_style  djangocms_text_ckeditor djangocms_video > cms_export.json --indent=2
```

I copied that file to the other app instance and tried to load it using the following command:

```
python manage.py loaddata cms_export.json
```

I got the following error:

```
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/cms_export.json': Page has no field named 'path'
```

cms_export.json snippet:

```
    [{
  "model": "cms.usersettings",
  "pk": 1,
  "fields": {
    "user": 2,
    "language": "en",
    "clipboard": 1
  }
},
{
  "model": "cms.usersettings",
  "pk": 2,
  "fields": {
    "user": 1,
    "language": "en",
    "clipboard": 7
  }
},
{
  "model": "cms.page",
  "pk": 4,
  "fields": {
    "path": "0004",
    "depth": 1,
    "numchild": 0,
    "created_by": "script",
    "changed_by": "xxxx",
    "parent": null,
    "creation_date": "2018-01-27T18:51:08.122Z",
    "changed_date": "2018-02-04T19:48:21.804Z",
    "publication_date": "2018-01-27T18:52:43.340Z",
    "publication_end_date": null,
    "in_navigation": true,
    "soft_root": false,
    "reverse_id": null,
    "navigation_extenders": null,
    "template": "base.html",
    "site": 1,
    "login_required": false,
    "limit_visibility_in_menu": null,
    "is_home": true,
    "application_urls": "",
    "application_namespace": null,
    "publisher_is_draft": true,
    "publisher_public": 5,
    "languages": "en",
    "revision_id": 0,
    "xframe_options": 0,
    "placeholders": [
      3,
      9
    ]
  }
},
{
  "model": "cms.page",
  "pk": 5,
  "fields": {
    "path": "0005",
    "depth": 1,
    "numchild": 0,
    "created_by": "admin",
    "changed_by": "xxxx",
    "parent": null,
    "creation_date": "2018-01-27T18:52:43.345Z",
    "changed_date": "2018-02-04T19:48:21.792Z",
    "publication_date": "2018-01-27T18:52:43.340Z",
    "publication_end_date": null,
    "in_navigation": true,
    "soft_root": false,
    "reverse_id": null,
    "navigation_extenders": null,
    "template": "base.html",
    "site": 1,
    "login_required": false,
    "limit_visibility_in_menu": null,
    "is_home": true,
    "application_urls": "",
    "application_namespace": null,
    "publisher_is_draft": false,
    "publisher_public": 4,
    "languages": "en",
    "revision_id": 0,
    "xframe_options": 0,
    "placeholders": [
      4,
      8
    ]
  }
},
{
  "model": "cms.page",
  "pk": 10,
  "fields": {
    "path": "0007",
    "depth": 1,
    "numchild": 0,
    "created_by": "script",
    "changed_by": "xxxx",
    "parent": null,
    "creation_date": "2018-01-31T19:56:22.494Z",
    "changed_date": "2018-02-04T18:49:06.843Z",
    "publication_date": "2018-01-31T19:57:23.405Z",
    "publication_end_date": null,
    "in_navigation": true,
    "soft_root": false,
    "reverse_id": null,
    "navigation_extenders": null,
    "template": "base.html",
    "site": 1,
    "login_required": false,
    "limit_visibility_in_menu": null,
    "is_home": false,
    "application_urls": null,
    "application_namespace": null,
    "publisher_is_draft": true,
    "publisher_public": 11,
    "languages": "en",
    "revision_id": 0,
    "xframe_options": 0,
    "placeholders": [
      26
    ]
  }
},]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is claiming that cms.page does not have a 'path' field, which could mean the model may not have the schema that you expect it to.

Comment: You are right! Figured out the problem. The new instance is using 3.5 version of django cms which rolled out 5 days back.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer this question. Thanks to @tinwhiskers

Divio team rolled out the stable 3.5 version of django-cms few days back.

My old instance is using 3.4.5 and the new instance where I'm trying to load the fixtures is using 3.5.0

Due to this, I'm having conflicting models.

Downgraded to 3.4.5 on my new instance and was able to successfully install fixtures.

Hope this helps anyone facing the same problem!